# Event Receiver in SharePoint using ItemAdded and ItemUpdated

Tags: development, events

I have an Event Receiver that is supposed to fire when a SPListItem is added or updated in a SPList that is a SharePoint Calendar.

I'm using two methods, ItemAdded and ItemUpdating. When I add a new item to the calendar both methods fire. The methods are supposed to send a mail and when I add a new item the ItemUpdated() sends 7 mails.

How do I make so that only the ItemAdded and not ItemUpdated fire whenever I add a new item to the list?

Thanks.

Comment: I know this is lame: Why not use Alerts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there are multiple events attached to the events?
That could explain why 7 mails are being sent..
You can see which event handlers have been registered with the [sharepoint-eventhandlers-manager](https://code.google.com/p/sharepoint-eventhandlers-manager/) or [SharePoint Event Receiver Manager (2007 & 2010)](https://speventreceiverman.codeplex.com/).
Also you may want to check the documentation of the [Table of SharePoint Events, Event Receivers, and Event Hosts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408183.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The [`ItemAdded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadded.aspx) is called just once on you event receiver; an item can be added just once. The [`ItemUpdating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemupdating.aspx) and/or [`ItemUpdated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemupdated.aspx) may be called multiple times. It will depend on what receivers or what workflows are active in the list and *what method they use do to update the list item*. Calling [`SPListItem.Update()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.update.aspx) triggers the events while calling the [`SPListItem.SystemUpdate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.systemupdate.aspx) does not, which makes the latter suitable for internal updates that should not be reported.

If you cannot "persuade" components that you installed to use `SystemUpdate()` for intermediate and other system changes ;-) you would have to think up some strategy how to avoid the "flocks of e-mails". For example, you could avoid an e-mail if it comes in less than a minute after the previous one.

I'd support Stefan's suggestion about [Alerts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897925.aspx). If you can make use of them you'd save time. I didn't notice an excessive amount of e-mails when using that. Either I was lucky having used only "well-behaving" event-receivers or Microsoft has some strategy to send e-mails when it makes sense.

--- Ferda

Answer (score 0):

If Ferda approach does not work for you there is a way to disable events when updating a value inside of an event receiver.

Lots of examples on the web, here are two:
http://www.mattjimison.com/blog/2011/05/11/disable-event-receivers-during-an-update/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466533/sharepoint-workflow-how-to-update-the-item-without-triggering-the-workflow-agai